# Google Drive showing old app icon beside Shortcut files

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a web application listed on the Marketplace that creates Google Drive Shortcuts ([as described here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts)).  This was all working as expected.  ​However, I've recently changed the Application Icon (via the Google Cloud Console > Drive UI Integration) and went through the app verification process again.  It has been roughly 2-3 weeks since then, but both new and existing shortcut files on drive.google.com are still showing the old icon instead of the new icon.

An interesting point is that it's only the file icon beside the shortcut file name that's not updating.  The new application icon is being used everywhere else, such as in the "New" menu, and the "Settings > Manage Apps" list.

How can I get drive.google.com to flush the old icon and show the new icon beside our shortcut files?

Comment: How did you change the app icon?

Comment: Hi, we changed the app icon through the "Drive UI Integration" page in the Google Cloud Console.  This was how we initially set the first icon as well.  Exact path is https://console.cloud.google.com/ > APIs & Services > Library > Google Drive API > Manage > Drive UI Integration

Comment: I would suggest filing a report on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) - or if it's add-on specific, this might be best to contact Google Workspace support [directly](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Comment: Will do - thanks @RafaGuillermo!